# NullReferenceException in DefaultUserSession when loading project with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, identityserver4

I am running a dotnet core 2.2 app with IdentityServer4 installed using Nuget. When I build a docker container and run, all works fine. When I deploy this container to my Google Kubernetes Engine cluster it fails on startup with the following:

```
{
 insertId:  "18ykz2ofg4ipm0"  
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-nndnb"   
  container.googleapis.com/namespace_name:  "my_namespace"   
  container.googleapis.com/pod_name:  "identity-deployment-5b8bd8745b-qn2v8"   
  container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stdout"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/my_project/logs/app"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-12-07T21:09:25.708527406Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "my_cluster"    
   container_name:  "app"    
   instance_id:  "4238697312444637243"    
   namespace_id:  "my_namespace"    
   pod_id:  "identity-deployment-5b8bd8745b-qn2v8"    
   project_id:  "my_project"    
   zone:  "europe-west2-b"    
  }
  type:  "container"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 textPayload:  "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
to an instance of an object.
   at 
IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultUserSession.RemoveSessionIdCookieAsync()
   at 
IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultUserSession.EnsureSessionIdCookieAsync()
   at 
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
"  
 timestamp:  "2018-12-07T21:09:17Z"  
}
```

As I mentioned, this works perfectly locally, and when running inside a docker container, only when within Kubernetes do I see these errors.

I'm not sure what I've missed here with kubernetes, but any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Running into the same (not from within kubernetes though)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I moved over to Openiddict and all is well now. Sorry I can't be more help

Comment: Thanks! I've drilled it down to _a_ .net core 2.2 issue (.net core 2.1 runs fine) so that might be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This vexed me in the last few days.  I suspect it has something to do with the recent deprecation of the former mechanism in app builder configuration:

```
   app.UseAuthentication().UseCookieAuthentication();  <-- no longer valid and apparently will not even compile now.
```

This has been replaced the following in the ConfigureServices section:

```
  services.AddAuthentication("YourCookieName")
    .AddCookie("YourCookieName", options =>
    {
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30.0);
    });
```

While I am not sure what the exact breaking change is for identityserver4, after cloning identityserver4 components and debugging I was able to isolate the the constructor for DefaultUserSession takes an IHttpContextAccessor that was arriving as null:

The constructor in question:

```
    public DefaultUserSession(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
        IAuthenticationHandlerProvider handlers,
        IdentityServerOptions options,
        ISystemClock clock,
        ILogger<IUserSession> logger)
    { ...
```

The following solution gets you past the error, though hopefully identityserver4 will make this moot in a near future release.

You need to add an IHttpContextAccessor service in ConfigureServices:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ... other code omitted ...
  services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor>(provider => new 
       LocalHttpContextAccessor(provider));
  ... other code omitted ...
}
```

The LocalHttpContextAccessor is just a private class in the configuration class as seen here:

```
private class LocalHttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
{
  public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; private set; }
  public HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }

  public LocalHttpContextAccessor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    this.httpContext = null;
  }

  public HttpContext HttpContext
  {
    get
    {
      return this.httpContext;
    }
    set
    {
      this.httpContext = null;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that at the point of configuring services, there is no current context to set, so I set it in a using block in the app builder configuration stage:

```
public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
  IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    httpContextAccessor = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    if (httpContextAccessor is LocalHttpContextAccessor)
    {
      ((LocalHttpContextAccessor)httpContextAccessor).httpContext = context;
    }
    await next();
  });
  ... other code omitted ...
  app.UseIdentityServer();
```

That will set the http context prior to running identity server code which fixes the bug.  The scoped service should be created individually for each request.  I've only recently made the full plunge into .net core from .net framework, so if there are scope or DI issues in that code that might lead to leaks or bad life-cycle, I'd appreciate the input.  That said, at the very least that code keeps identity server 4 from crashing with the core 2.2+.

Comment: I could not get this solution to work. The scoped nature of the IHttpContextAccessor is different from what's expected (Transient). Causing additional composition exceptions for me.

Comment: I am surprised this isn't fixed in most recent version of IdentityServer4, but I have been working with the preview version on .net core 3.0.  Is the issue that context is wrong or that it's null?  Might be using a factory against service provider to get better results.

Comment: When I changed it to Transient, the context is eventually not set. I say eventually because stepping through IdServer it is set in a lot of instances. This is refactor on a legacy system, and I don't use IdServer a lot, so didn't want to invest too much time in getting the integration tests working. (Already spent 3 days).

Comment: Ouch.. sorry to hear that. I had a similar lengthy experience, unfortunately.  I have been using preview version for .net core 3.0 and found it doesn't have the same issue with the http context. While I believe they've fixed the issue, browsing the latest code it's not easy to confirm that. I had an issue with CORS not working with URL with more than host in it -- to diagnose that, I ended up downloading all of idserver4's code base and adding it into my solution.  It only took a few hours to get all the projects playing nicely -- if you are similary stuck, you might want to try that as well.

Comment: It's also not an issue with 3.0 but it's in preview for a bit longer.  While I enjoy .net core 3.0, there are a number of breaking changes you have to changes things for -- was a huge pain early on but more recently Microsoft is putting out decent documentation for that process.  I think we are still a couple of weeks away from it's final release, as well... so might not be great option for you atm.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not an option for me anyway as it needs to run on-prem on aging hardware.

Comment: I will confirm that none of that code is needed in the .core 3.0 release of IdentityServer4.  Things seem to be behaving well so far making the configuration fairly trivial compared to the troubleshooting nightmare I went through getting it working in core 2.x versions.